# Remove elements from an array that contains particular string in swift

Tags: macos, swift, swift-array

I have an array.

```
var array_var: [String] = [
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/convert?fit=crop&w=200&h=200&rotate=exif",
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/convert?fit=crop&w=320&h=300&rotate=exif",
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]
```

So I just want to remove(exclude) the elements that contains the string `convert?fit=crop` from the array.

So how can we remove them by using Swift??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use filter method:

```
array_var = array_var.filter {
    $0.rangeOfString("convert?fit=crop") == nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it

```
var array_var: [String] = [
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/convert?     fit=crop&w=200&h=200&rotate=exif",
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/convert?fit=crop&w=320&h=300&rotate=exif",
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

var newArray: [String] = []


for i in 0...array_var.count - 1 {
if array_var[i].rangeOfString("convert?fit=crop") != nil {

    newArray.append(array_var[i])


}
}
array_var = newArray
```